# Why can't I see API Key prompt when connecting to my own data source?

Tags: looker-studio

I'm having trouble figuring out why can't I see a prompt to enter API key. I can connect directly without any authentication. Why is the API key ignored?

auth.js file:

```
function getAuthType() {
  return {
    type: 'KEY'
  };
}

function validateKey(key) {
  var url = 'http://myapi.com/endpoint?api_key=' + key;
  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType":"application/json"
  };

  var response = JSON.parse(
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
  );
  Logger.log(response.data.length > 0)
  return response.data.length > 0;
}

function isAuthValid() {
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var key = userProperties.getProperty('dscc.key');

  return validateKey(key);
}

function resetAuth() {
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  userProperties.deleteProperty('dscc.key');
}

function setCredentials(request) {
  var key = request.key;

  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  userProperties.setProperty('dscc.key', key);
  return {
    errorCode: 'NONE'
  };
}

function isAdminUser() {
  return false;
}
```

The `Logger.log` output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using a `http` url. We've moved our API to `https` and the problem is solved. Data Studio doesn't show any error messages and skips the auth step. This is very strange.

**Edit:** A month later, while reviewing the document I noticed that Data Studio is already asking for us an `https` url.

> Each prefix must use `https://`, not `http://`. <sup>[source](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest#whitelisting_urls)</sup>

Comment: Interesting find. For `Logger.log(response.data.length > 0)`, are you getting `true` in the log?

Comment: nice to see you here Minhaz. yeah it was returning `true`.

Comment: Glad you figured out the issue. I think either there was already some legitimate value stored in script properties for `dscc.key` OR somehow `http://myapi.com/endpoint?api_key=` was returning a non-blank arrary for `response.data`.